# Flutter : custom gauge segmented bar

Tags: flutter, progress-bar, customization

I have a variable value from 1 to 5000

And would like to create a custom bar chart that represents each tick as 200, so that I have 5 segments of 5 bars x 5 segments.

What's the best way to create this in flutter (like in the image)?

[image: refer lcd-ish version]

The closest that I found in the documentation is the demo of battery in sync fusion library. But I think my understanding of the library is limited. It uses multiple linear range, with calculation that I can't seems to wrap my head around it.

Is it also possible to use flutter stack to "mask" a normal default bar for the segments and mini bars?

Comment: You can start with `Row` & `Container`s inside it, update values (colors, in this case) of the containers according to the values passed.

Comment: you mean each of the bar is a container?